# How can I keep the button disable of previous page even after I visiting next page or after refreshing previous

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code but it enable the button after refreshing

```
function disablebtn(){
    $("input[type=checkbox]").prop("disabled", true);
    $(".buttons11").prop("disabled", true);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You can't. You need to store data in cookie or a database/file, and refer to it to enable or disable the button.

Comment: You could work with a cookie if you want to keep the state of your button between pageloads

Comment: Okay..thank u.. i will try

Answer (score 2):

You should use HTML5 Web storages for such requirements.

The following code should provide you an idea:

```
// For after refresh or later navigation to the page
if (localStorage.btnStatus === "disabled") {
    disablebtn();
}

function disablebtn() {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").prop("disabled", true);
    $(".buttons11").prop("disabled", true);
    localStorage.btnStatus = "disabled";
    return true;
}
```